# Convert yyyy-mm-dd to JS timestamp

Tags: javascript, datetime, timestamp, utc

Theres lots of questions about how to convert a timestamp to yyyy-mm-dd but I am trying to do it the other way around.

I have an array of dates in the format 2013-02-25 but I want them to be js timestamps.

I have an array of dates such as `["2013-02-25", "2013-02-22", "2013-02-21"]` and ive tried

`new Date(dateArray[0]).getTime() / 1000;`

but this gives the wrong result as "2013-02-25" is converted to 1361750400 which is Fri, 16 Jan 1970 18:15:50 GMT

any suggestions on how to do this in javascript please?

Comment: What's the relationship between values like `442.80` and a yyyy-mm-dd date?

Comment: No. your date comes out as `1361750400000` (3 extra zeroes). that's a proper JS millisecond timestamp. 1361750400 (without the zeroes) is a standard unixtimestamp, which is feb 25th/2013.

Comment: sorry i pasted the wrong values, ive edited my question to show the array of dates. Also when I do console.log it outputs 1361750400 so im not sure where the 3 extra zeroes have gone.

Comment: @James You are doing / 1000 , that's where the extra 3 zeros are.

Comment: Thanks Benjamin, ive been working too long today and my brain is fried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:** Question was updated to use this code for trying to parse dates.

Your problem now is that you do `new Date(dateArray[0]).getTime() / 1000;` . You shouldn't divide by 1000. Try `new Date(dateArray[0]).getTime()`.

---

I think the obvious solution is the one you missed :

```
var date = new Date("2013-02-25")// contains Mon Feb 25 2013 02:00:00
```

- [Here is the spec for date](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#page-14)
- [w3c date and time format](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime)

Comment: @Kyle Thanks, though actually if you're going to add an MDN link might be the one that describes what the constructor is doing: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

Comment: `Date.parse()` is a method of the `Date` global object, not a constructor.

Comment: @Kyle Date.parse is how the constructor accepting a date string works :)

Comment: I see what you mean. Is firefox 4 the only browser that supports that subset of ISO-8601? Or do other browsers support it?